# convert this line of code into jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

following html coding are for the file uploading. I have a function which i want to write in jQuery style.

```
<form method="post" action="upload">

  <input type="file" id ="file_upload_id"/>
  <input type="submit" id= "dont_click" />

  <input type ="button"  id ="only_click_me" onClick="clickme();"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function clickme(){
       document.getElementID("file_upload_id").click(); // 

       document.getElementbyID("file_upload_id").onChange =  function() {
                     document.getElementById('dont_click').click()
                 };
    }
</script>
```

This is how i want to convert the lines of coding :

```
 $(function(){
    $("#file_upload_id").click(function() {
           onChange : function(){
                         $("#dont_click").click();
                    }
     });
 });
```

Comment: This code will result in many syntax errors.

Comment: @karolis : syntax error? i just tried to explain in short

Comment: Yeah, but with so many mistakes it's not clear how exactly you expect the code to work.

Comment: @Karolis : ohh let me redefine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like that,

```
$('#file_upload_id').trigger('click');
$('#file_upload_id').change(function () {
  $('#dont_click').trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This isn't really a question.  More like: just do work for me.  :-P

Anyway:

```
$("#file_upload_id").click();
$("#file_upload_id").change(function(){ $('#dont_click').click(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('#only_click_me').click(function() {
        $('#file_upload_id').click();
    });

    $('#file_upload_id').change(function() {
        $('#dont_click').click();
    });
});
```